# Identify this animated movie about humans, trolls/goblins, and villainous aliens?

Tags: identify-this-movie, anime

Ah, I need help finding an animated movie I watched a whole bunch as lil kid in the 2000’s so this movie probably goes back from the 80’s to the early 2000’s. It’s really all about these trolls or goblins that can turn into the normal everyday household items (IE: A brush, a set of drums, a broom) during the daytime and it’s about how a normal everyday boy becomes friends with one of these trolls/goblins and they beat the villains of movie, which happen to be aliens that came to Earth to steal children for slave labor on their planet together.

The movie starts out with this excavation crew clearing out space and digging holes in the ground, well, they uncover a bunch of these household items just in the dirt. Well, it starts getting dark and the excavation crew heads home and come night time, these household items turn into goblins or trolls. They celebrate their freedom and make a new home in a hollowed out tree at the top of this hill, overlooking the city or suburbs. Some time passes and pretty soon this alien ship appears one night and they pick a fight with them. So the goblins and trolls turn into their item forms and beat the ship, as the ship admits defeat and flies off, it fires a laser and hits one of them. I think he may have died and so all of his friends start crying, the funny thing is, whenever they cry, it starts to rain and I guess it cuts off to this elderly couple in a house who remark on how whenever these creatures cry, it pours. Cut to our main character, a typical boy who attends a Japanese school (I remember this part because the teachers switched classes and the students didn’t that and the door slid open). I think he may have been dubbed by a dude with a New Jersey accent but I am unsure and don’t trust myself. Well, a new student arrives in the class, a girl he developed a crush on and I guess we were supposed to be suspicious of her in the beginning because they put emphasis on her eyes and how they almost seemed to be taking pictures of the students she interacted with.

Later on, I guess this kid decided he was going to go talk to her at night or bring something back to her so he was hopping fences and going through people’s backyards and he runs into this Pitbull dog that chases him away and takes his shoe. This is about the time the human boy runs into his soon-to-be best friend, the young troll/goblin. They fight for a bit before the human kid accidently takes off the troll/goblins horn, to which, he starts to cry (and I think it starts raining). The human boy apologizes and superglues his horn back on. They sort of become friends after this and the troll/goblin saves the human boys life when one of those mover trucks almost hits him in the road and the goblin/troll magic’s the car on top of a building (Y’know how they put those moving trucks on top of building to advertise, it was kind of like that only the people were still in the car).

This is the part that gets kind of fuzzy to me. I know the new girl takes two kids from the class and brings them over to her house to meet her game developing grandfather and let them try out a new game he’s developing, to which, they disappear after playing it. I also know the boy took the troll/goblin home after he turned into a brush in the morning and his mother threw it out commenting on how dirty it was. The human boy ends up chasing the garbage truck and diving into the sewers trying to get his friend who berates him for letting his mom throw him out into the dumpster. This is where it gets really fuzzy to me but I do know that some goblin/troll king finds out about the boy and young goblin/trolls friendship and takes them both to his castle where they threaten to kill the young boy in a fire-pit. After that fight, the king tells them about how they can say this mantra together and become one person? Half human and half troll/goblin and they can fly. At this point, most of the kids from his class have disappeared and all of the troll/goblin creatures from the tree have been caught and thrown in a cell with the rest of the kids. They go to interrogate the girl and find out they brainwashed her and how her grandfather wasn’t really her grandfather and that she was kidnapped as well. They go to save the children and troll/goblins and end up skydiving out of the ship while they help lower everyone to the ground safely. And yeah, that’s basically it. Besides the ending where the aliens crash land into a pig pen and they remark on how they can bring back the pigs to do their work for them.

Any help finding out the title of this movie would be helpful as I’ve been looking for like 6 years with absolutely no leads other than it’s possibly between the 1980’s to late 2000’s and that it was possibly made in japan. I watched it off of a VHS tape and faintly recall that the movie could have possibly been named after whatever the creatures were called?? I’ve only called them goblin and trolls because they were brown-ish green and had horns and wore raggy clothes. Thank you.

Comment: All I could find so far was this same question on Reddit https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/23m6sr/need_help_finding_obscure_dubbed_anime/

Answer (score 11):

An extremely detailed ID question like that deserves a reward. ;)

You're looking for [Koby-Koby (AKA Little Monsters: The Adventures of Koby & the Oakey Dokeys)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4767910/combined) from 1995, which is just *barely* on IMDb. From an [online synopsis](http://www.whodany.com/koby.html):

> Because of a magic spell cast by the King of the Little Creatures, discarded household objects like brooms and cups turn into Oakey Dokeys at night. One of our heroes is a really feisty little Oakey Dokey named CODY. And although most Oakey Dokeys don't really trust humans, Cody's best friend is a boy named BOBBY. Cody and Bobby have a very special friendship, in fact, it's absolutely magical. You see, they have a way that combines their energies and turns them into one very super-powerful boy named... KOBY. Although the Oakey Dokeys are occasionally mischievous, there are other creatures called HOBGOBLINS which are always mischievous.

Everything you mentioned is there; well-remembered. Here are the first 15 minutes:

Comment: Yeah, agreed, but we can't reward bounty to asker.

Comment: @AJ I just meant rewarding it with an answer. ;) But unfortunately, you're right.